# React - Why is the output different? Is it regarding destructuring of props?

Tags: reactjs

- **Object** Object that I will be passing into components

  ```
    const parts = {
        part1: {
            name: 'Fundamentals of React',
            exercises: 10
        },
            part2: {
            name: 'Using props to apss data',
            exercises: 7
        },
        part3: {
            name: 'State of a component',
            exercises: 14
        }
    }
  ```
- **1)** Version 1 of Components Content & Part

  ```
    const Content = ({content}) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Part name={content.part1.name} exercises={content.part1.exercises} />
                <Part name={content.part2.name} exercises={content.part2.exercises} />
                <Part name={content.part3.name} exercises={content.part3.exercises} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    const Part = ({name, exercises}) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{name} {exercises}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
  ```
- **2)** Version 2 of Components Content & Part

  ```
    const Content = (content) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Part parts={content.part1} />
                <Part parts={content.part2} />
                <Part parts={content.part3} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    const Part = (parts) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{parts.name} {parts.exercises}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
  ```

Tried out a new React course and did not understand why code 1) worked in displaying the output but 2) did not work. Anyone care to enlighten more on destructuring the prop received and what edits can I make to 2) to make it have the same display as 1) Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear how you are calling your function, we would need to see that to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you're passing `name` and `exercises` props to the component, and you're destructuring them from the props object passed to the component.

In your second example, you're passing a `parts` prop to the component but **not** destructuring, so your `parts` parameter refers to the props object, not to the `parts` prop.

So basically, yes, you should be destructuring in the second option (as in the first) if you want to access the `parts` prop you're passing.

---

Perhaps somewhat tangential, but if you were trying to make the usage of the `Part` component less verbose, you could use spread notation since your parts objects directly have the `name` and `exercises` props (and no other props):

```
const Content = ({content}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Part {...content.part1} />
            <Part {...content.part2} />
            <Part {...content.part3} />
        </div>
    );
};

const Part = ({name, exercises}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{name} {exercises}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

But it's probably best to do that only when you know the parts objects will have only the props the component expects. Components ignore extra props, but it's still not ideal to pass them things they won't use.

Answer (score 0):

React components work in this way: A functional component expects a props argument, which is an object. In case you don't pass any props to the component, the props object is just an empty object.

Version 1 of your code works because the `Content` component expects a `prop` called `content`, which you are destructuring like this:

```js
const Content = ({content}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Part {...content.part1} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

The same component can be rewritten like this if you don't use the destructuring technique:

```js
const Content = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Part {...props.content.part1} />
             ...
        </div>
    );
};
```

Notice that once you don't use the destructuring technique, every prop you pass becomes a property of the `props` object.

So, your version 2 won't work because while you are allowed to name your first argument of the React function as you want, you have to understand that it will be passed as `props`. Thus, the Content component refers to the `props` as `content` and can be refactored like this:

```js
const Content = (content) => {
      return (
          <div>
              <Part parts={content.content.part1} />
              ...
          </div>
      )
  }
```

Technically, the above code will work, but it is not readable. Notice how content is chained to another content `content.content`.

Instead, you could adopt naming the first parameter of the functional component as `props`, which makes it more readable. So, your version 2 would be like this:

```js
const Content = (props) => {
      return (
          <div>
              <Part parts={props.content.part1} />
              ...
          </div>
      )
  }

  const Part = (props) => {
      return (
          <div>
              <p>{props.parts.name} {props.parts.exercises}</p>
          </div>
      )
  }
```

And now, the only difference between version 1 and 2 is that version 1 is using the destructuring technique, while version 2 is not.